# vertically image in div

Tags: image, vertical-alignment

This is the code that i have:

```
<div class="news-container">
    <div class="flex_column av_two_third flex_column_div first">
    <div class="news-date"><h2>jan 2015</h2></div>
    <div class="news-entry">
       <div class="news-title"><h2>new title</h2></div>
       <div class="news-source">wearhouse</div>
       <div class="news-content">excerpt goes here.</div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="flex_column av_one_third flex_column_div">myimage</div>
</div>
```

how can i get the image to float in the middle vertically of it's div.

i tried adding this code:

```
.img{
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -100px;
}
```

but because i have padding of 30px on the news containter  it doesn't seem to work properly.

I have my live page at:
http://nodal.rudtek.com/about-us/press-room/news-features/

Answer (score 0):

Try using `line-height`, usually it works perfectly for me, so chances are it will for you too. Hope it helps.

Comment: To the style of the <img> tag :) Good luck!

Comment: it doesn't make a difference. at all:
'.img {line-height:20px;}'

Comment: Okay, set the image to `display: inline-block` and the div it is in to  `display: inline-block`, then, set the image height to 'height:100%` and `vertical-align: middle`, this should center the image in the div. Hope this works!

Comment: What I mean is this http://jsfiddle.net/kizu/4RPFa/4570/ This is not my code, but someone else's, but works very well too, give it a go.